# How to get list box value from client side and use it in server side in GWT/google web toolkit?

Tags: gwt, listbox, client

i have a problem on maintaining an application. I didnt develop this and i'm quite not familiar with GWT framework. Can anyone help me on how can i get the values from a list box from the client side and use it on server side? Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Short: You need to define a Asynchronous service to send the values to the server and process it.

In Detail:
1) Define a Async Service. More info [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html)

2) Async service should be able to either accept a list of strings of a class that contain all the values that you need to access at server side.

3) Process the values in server side and return the value you intended to send back to client (if you have to).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from Vikky:

You can get the text of any item with getItemText function ([link to doc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html#getItemText%28int%29)) and the index of the selected item with getSelectedIndex function.

getItemText(getSelectedIndex()) will do the job...